# Problem while loading modal popup window in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

When am trying to add a modal window on the Navigation bar, when am click on the Open Modal button it looks blurred and does not get any action on the Modal window.
The same code works fine outside the navbar. Also checked for previous posts and added script files and .navbar-right utility classes, but not working.

navigation.jsp file is different

My code is as follows,

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myNavModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>      
</div>
```

**Upload**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmTV1.png)

Comment: Can you please Provide Url?

Comment: <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
    <li>
 <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myNavModal" data-remote="false" ><strong><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload</strong></a>
 </li>
</ul>